# Closed-form of prime zeta values

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, closed-form

The [prime zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) is defined as

$$P(s)=\sum_{p\,\in\mathrm{\mathcal P}} \frac{1}{p^s},$$

where $\mathcal P$ is the set of prime numbers. It converges for all $\Re(s)>1$.

There is a related function defined as

$$\int_s^\infty P(t)\,dt = \sum_p \frac{1}{p^s\log p}.$$

**Question.** Are there any known closed-form value of $P(s)$ or $\int_s^\infty P(t)\,dt$?

Comment: No, there aren't any.

Comment: @Lucian actually you should make this an answer.It will be really an answer and so simple(I am not kidding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no closed form for the prime zeta function, but it can be computed as
$$
P(s)=\sum_{n\ge1} \mu(n)\frac{\log\zeta(ns)}{n}
$$
which is more efficient than the standard form. In some sense these are adding in different directions, and a more efficient method can be obtained by adding in both directions and subtracting the overlap.